# ViewPager, remove current view with animation

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation

I have a `ViewPager` that has `TabView`s as child.

To remove a tab from viewPager, I'm doing this:

```
public void removeTab(TabView tabView) { 

        //implement animation here....

        //animation finished, remove from Array: 

        for (int i = 0; i < tabs.size(); i++) {
            if(tabView.getTabId().equals(tabs.get(i).getTabId())) {
                //tab is this
                tabs.remove(tabs.get(i));
                break;
            }
        }

        //update tabs in adapter with new 'tabs'
        this.myPagerAdapter.setTabs(tabs);
        myPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

How can I delete it with animation? I tried a few different approaches (`tabView.animate()` etc) but not working.

Can anyone point me to right direction?

Thanks.

Screenshot:
[image]